# Running Code After Response.End() and Alternatives for it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm exporting code to a csv file and the process terminates with Response.End() as expected and the SendEmail routine in the Finally clause is never executed. I need to run SendEmail() after Response.End and looking for suggestions. If just remove Response.End, then the csv file is never created.

```
 Protected Sub ExportExcel(ByVal Vendor As String)
    Dim MyConnection As SqlConnection
    MyConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BusOpsConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("p_BPOTracker_ClosedReport", MyConnection)
    With cmd
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vendor", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Vendor
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IssueStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Closed"

    End With

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim myDataTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(myDataTable)

    Dim FileDate As String = Replace(FormatDateTime(Now(), DateFormat.ShortDate), "/", "")
    Dim attachmentName As String = "BPOTracker_Closed_Report_" & Vendor & "_" & FileDate & "_.csv"

    Try
        MyConnection.Open()
        Response.Clear()
        Response.ClearHeaders()
        Dim writer As New CsvWriter(Response.OutputStream, ","c, Encoding.Default)
        writer.WriteAll(myDataTable, True)
        writer.Close()

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & attachmentName)
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Response.End()

    Finally

        If MyConnection.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then MyConnection.Close()
        MyConnection.Dispose()
        MyConnection = Nothing
        myDataTable.Dispose()
        myDataTable = Nothing

        Thread.Sleep(3000)
        SendEmail(Vendor, attachmentName)

    End Try

End Sub

Sub SendEmail(ByVal Vendor As String, ByVal attachmentFileName As String)
'Send Email
End Sub
```

Comment: "I need to run SendEmail after Response.End" - why? What's your reasoning for that? And why do you have a Thread.Sleep in your code? Why are you serving a CSV file with an Excel MIME type?

Comment: SendEmail() sends an email with the csv file that is created as an attachment. The Thread.Sleep pauses the code to make sure that the file is created before trying to send the email.  I'm using CSVWriter component and the documentation states to use  Excel MIME type

Comment: But *why* must SendEmail be called after Response.End? Why can't you call it before? The Thread.Sleep is completely useless here, you have no asynchronous code therefore it's guaranteed that the code before it will have completed by the time you get there. The Thread.Sleep is only artificially slowing down your code and having a negative performance impact on your server. Remove it. As for the documentation saying to use Excel MIME type with CSV - what documentation? Where does it say that?

Comment: How would I send the email with the attachment if the attachment hasn't even been created yet in ExportExcel()?

Comment: I didn't say to send the send the email before the attachment is created. I said to send it before the Response.End. Do you see the difference between those?

Comment: I understand but the csv file that needs to be exported isn't populated correctly until Response.End. All of the client side source code from the .aspx page ends up in the csv file without Response.End.

Comment: Don't wire the CsvWriter to write the file directly to the output stream. Write it to a file on disk on the server (or even to memory if it's not a large file). Then you can send it as an attachment on the email and then you can write it to the response and then call Response.End after all that is done. The way you've got it now, the only way you'll be able to send the email is the client saves the file to a location that the server has access to and the path lines up exactly. Obviously that's not a realistic scenario.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mason AddWithValue is much less evil for MySql. MySql encodes type information differently and binds it later at the server, so AddWithValue() is less problematic there.

Comment: Side trip, but there's no need in modern DB to set objects to Nothing when you're done with them. That's a hold-over from ancient vbscript/vb6, and it just doesn't make sense to do with .Net, where the garbage collector does it's job more correctly.

Comment: You're using AddWithValue with SQL Server, which isn't a good idea. For an explanation of why and how to fix it, see [AddWithValue is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: I'll change AddWithValue as well. Yes, using SQL Server 2016 here.

Comment: @mason Ooops, you're right. I saw the "my" at the beginning of the connection name while skimming through :o

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yep, I've definitely done that before. user3641053: probably not a good idea to put "my" in front of your variable names, especially around database code. Generally in our own code we just call it "connection" and "command" unless we're dealing with multiple connections or commands, in which case we'll give it some name to delineate the difference, such as "sourceConnection" and "destinationConnection" if we're dealing with two different databases and one is logically a source of data and the other is logically a destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the issue here is that you don't have a clear way of getting the generated file as an attachment to the file. Your CSVWriter is writing directly to the HTTP Response. Instead you can write to a file location on disk, or to memory. At that point you can send the email with the file as an attachment. Then you can write the file to the response and then end the response.

Your methods could use some more breakdown. I suggest one method for generating the file, one method for sending the file to an email (you've got that one already) and another method for writing the file to the response.